# How Galileo could both possibly say that Earth is revolving around the Sun and develop the Galilean relativity?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, galileo

I always have been curious about this part of the History of Science. To claim that Earth is orbiting the Sun instead of the opposite is equivalent to change one absolute referential (Earth) to another one (the Sun); something Galilean relativity forbids. So how come Galileo is credited for both the statement and the theory?

Comment: [Galilean relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance) concerns inertial frames, i.e. those moving linearly and uniformly. Rotating frames are not inertial, so between the Earth and the Sun the real center of rotation is privileged: centrifugal and Coriolis forces are absent in its frame.

Comment: Galilean relativity is a group transformation that states, among other things, there is no absolute referential. Before Galileo, Earth was the center of the Universe, after him, it became the Sun. Both statements are false. In the Earth referential, the Sun is revolving around Earth, it is not an illusion, every year, the Sun comes back to the same position. In the Sun referential it is the opposite. Galileo is the father of the Galilean relativity and most likely understood that.

Comment: You are confusing Galilean relativity with Einstein's [general principle of relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_relativity#General_principle_of_relativity). Galilean relativity easily combines with an absolute frame, which Newton explicitly did in *Principia* and showed that rotational motion is non-relative, see [Newton's bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_argument). Galileo certainly did not use modern formulations with transformation groups either, even for his case. That is the work of 19th century.

Comment: I am not confusing anything. Classical mechanics is based on Galilean relativity. There is no mechanical experiment that can distinguished two referentials in mutual translation and therefore there is no absolute referential. When Maxwell's equations were developed, Lorentz  found out it was incompatible with the Galilean group and derived its transformation.
https://www.tau.ac.il/education/muse/museum/galileo/principle_relativity.html

Comment: If you do not know the answer, that's fine, but please do not try to answer. https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/10.0000303

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify something. By my understanding, the term "Galilean relativity" ordinarily refers to later applications of the principles that were discovered by Galileo, those applications taking place for example in the realm of Newtonian mechanics. The key historical point here is that without Galileo's discoveries, those later applications would either have been impossible or someone else would have to have reproduced those discoveries. But you seem to be referring to "Galilean relativity" as something enunciated by Galileo himself. Can you say clarify this point?

Comment: Galilean relativity is summarized in modern terms by the Galilean transformation: If the referential R' moves relative to R at the velocity v along 0x, then:
$$\begin{cases}x'=x+v.t\\y'=y\\z'=z\\t'=t\end{cases} $$
One of the consequence of this transformation is the non existence of an absolute referential and the equivalence of the laws of mechanics in all inertial referentials.

Comment: In plain English: Galileo is supposed to have both  said that Earth is not the center of the Universe,  it is revolving around the Sun (so making the Sun the center of the Universe which is wrong),  and in the same time have said that both the Earth and Sun referentials are equivalent (which is true).  So either the general populace never understood him or he was claiming one thing and its opposite in the same time.

Comment: The equivalence of the laws of mechanics in all inertial reference frames does not apply to rotating frames, because they are not inertial. So the Earth and the Sun frames are not equivalent by your own statement of Galilean relativity. And in non-inertial frames the laws of mechanics are not equivalent to those in inertial frames because of [fictitious forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force).

Comment: @ Conifold  In the two bodies Kepler problem of finding the orbits the two systems are assumed punctual. You can solve the problem in the Sun referential, the Earth referential or the center of mass referential (this is the one that simplifies the calculation). They are all equivalent for point masses.
Guies I have been in Physics for 40 years. I am looking for an answer from an Historian, not some ill considered comments about Physics.

Comment: I would be interested in quotes that explain what Galileo _exactly_ said, because saying "Earth revolves around the Sun" and "the Sun is at the center of the universe" are _definitely not_ the same things. It's important to know which of the two claims he exactly said. The point is, in _any inertial reference frame,_ both the Earth and Sun orbit around the barycenter, which is very near to the Sun's center of mass. This way of formulating things shows there is no contradiction here whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

For Galileo, the relativity principle was an observational principle. When he writes about the thought experiment on a moving ship where the observer cannot recognize that there is movement, it is clear to the reader that it is indeed a *moving* ship. So for Galileo, there can be an absolute reference system, where the Sun is at the center, and then there are all these empirically equivalent systems, such as two moving ships, whose movements cannot ever be observed. There is no contradiction between those.

This duality persisted until the early twentieth century. We find this for example in Newton, who believed in absolute space and empirically equivalent inertial systems; in Maxwell, who believed in the ether but whose equations are equivalent for moving systems; and in Lorentz, who assumed an absolute ether system but had it as a principle that the ether contracted in such a way that each inertial system was by principle empirically equivalent. It was only with Poincaré and Einstein that someone thought this duality was particularly problematic.

Comment: So basically Galileo was as wrong as the Church by claiming that Earth and the other planets were orbiting the Sun and thus making the Sun an absolute referential. It may be easier to use the heliocentric system for studying the motion of planets but for the 99.9999% of the the population who does not care about that, the Geocentric referential is as good and a more practical choice.

Comment: Please note that I have never claimed that Galileo said that the Sun was at the center of the universe. I have noted that claimed that the Earth revolved around the Sun and that this is not necessarily in contradiction to his claim that an observer does not notice the difference between these reference systems. In fact, I was hard pressed to find any statement from Galileo about the Sun in the Universe. You must be careful not to conflate Galileo's ideas with those who followed him.